# Is it possible to edit a server group in spinnaker?

Tags: spinnaker

I'm experimenting with spinnaker but am finding I often need to edit a server group after creating it. However, it's not clear how to do this from the UI.

Is it possible to edit an existing server group using Spinnaker?

Answer (score 2):

Spinnaker heavily relies on the "immutable infrastructure" approach, meaning infrastructure & artifact definitions should not be changed once they're created. Here's a [nice slide deck](https://www.slideshare.net/profyclub_ru/8-mitchell-hashimoto-hashicorp) providing some rational.

As a result, you need to create a new server group when you want to apply changes to it. You can do this via a "Clone" operation, shown below:

[image: clone operation]

An even more robust solution would be to codify the definition of your server group in the pipeline that deploys it, and to only make changes to the definition there - rerunning the deployment pipeline when you want to make changes.